# Adding units to Lazarus

Tags: pascal, lazarus

How can I add units to Lazarus, e.g. (crt,sysutils), specifically wingraph?

Comment: wingraph comes with windows versions of FPC/Lazarus only.

Comment: It didnt come with mine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the project setting you have to specify the location of the unit you want to use (Menu **Project**, **Project options**, **Compiler options**, **Paths** and finally **Other units files**)

[image]

You can add absolute or relative paths. Relative paths uses the project file (the ***. lpr**) directory as base directory.

Some macros also exist, as shown in the screenshot (e.g `$(PathMacro)`). Read [more here](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/IDE_Macros_in_paths_and_filenames#IDE_macro_format)